# Jsp/Servlet Hello World With JBoss

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, intellij-idea, jboss

I am going to run my jsp/ servlet in JBoss application server.

Here is my `index.jsp` page:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title> hello </title>
</head>
<body>
        Hello World
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my servlet class:

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        out.write("hello , world");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

And `web.xml` configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>helloServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>helloServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Why i am getting `404 not found` in `http://localhost:8080/index.jsp` and in `http://localhost:8080/hello` ?

I am using Intellij IDEA .

(There is no error in log)

**update**

```
Connected to server
[2015-09-16 02:29:07,679] Artifact EeTest1:ear exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
02:29:07,912 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "EeTest1_ear_exploded.ear" (runtime-name: "EeTest1_ear_exploded.ear")
02:29:07,990 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "web.war")
02:29:08,502 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /EeTest1Web
02:29:08,605 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "EeTest1_ear_exploded.ear" (runtime-name : "EeTest1_ear_exploded.ear")
[2015-09-16 02:29:08,651] Artifact EeTest1:ear exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2015-09-16 02:29:08,652] Artifact EeTest1:ear exploded: Deploy took 972 milliseconds
```

Comment: What is your project (or application) name?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The project name is `EeTest1`

Comment: Then your root context is (probably) `EeTest1`. Try `http://localhost:8080/EeTest1/hello`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i get `Error 404` again.

Comment: Is your application being deployed? You mention there are no errors in the log, what about success messages?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch See `update` section.

Comment: If you have not set any <context-root> in your configuration then by default the root context is the name of the generated war.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then your web application is available at http://localhost:8080/EeTest1Web/hello and http://localhost:8080/EeTest1Web/ (for http://localhost:8080/EeTest1Web/index.jsp). The relevant portion from your log message is

> Registered web context: /EeTest1Web